# Calculate variance of an estimator of value

Tags: probability

I have an estimator of value $X,$ which is equal $\frac{1}{2}$: $\hat{X}= \frac{2}{3}X_{1} + \frac{5}{3}X_{2} - \frac{1}{3}X_{3}$.

How to calculate its variance?

Is it: $D(\hat{X}) = (\frac{2}{3})^{2}X_{1} + (\frac{5}{3})^{2}X_{2} - (\frac{1}{3})^{2}X_{3} = (\frac{2}{3})^{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} + (\frac{5}{3})^{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} - (\frac{1}{3})^{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2}?$

Answer (score 1):

First notice that **Variance** calculate the variation around the mean, discarding the signs. That means surely you haven't a negative term like, $-(\frac{1}{3})^2X_3$, in variance! But if you know that $X_i$'s are independent, so you was so close:
$$V(X) = (\frac{2}{3})^2 V(X_{1}) + (\frac{5}{3})^2 V(X_{2}) + (-\frac{1}{3})^2 V(X_{3})$$